# CSS3 transitions not working on android correctly

Tags: css, less, css-transitions

Can anyone see anything in the below code that would cause issues on Android?

On android, when the code is used it fails on the first attempt, gives a blank screen, then if you tap again it works.

```
.csstransforms.csstransitions.js #nav {
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-100%, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate(-100%, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate(-100%, 0);
    -o-transform: translate(-100%, 0);
    transform: translate(-100%, 0);
    .backface-visibility(hidden);
}

.csstransforms.csstransitions.js #inner-wrapper {
    left: 0 !important;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate(0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate(0, 0);
    transform: translate(0, 0);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 500ms ease;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 500ms ease;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 500ms ease;
    transition: transform 500ms ease;
    .backface-visibility(hidden);
}

.csstransforms.csstransitions.js-nav #inner-wrapper {
    -webkit-transform: translate(70%, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    -moz-transform: translate(70%, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    -ms-transform: translate(70%, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    -o-transform: translate(70%, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    transform: translate(70%, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1);
}
```

I should mention, I am using a LESS mixins, so the backface part is:

```
.backface-visibility (@backface) {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: @backface;
    -moz-backface-visibility: @backface;
    -ms-backface-visibility: @backface;
    -o-backface-visibility: @backface;
    backface-visibility: @backface;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What version of Android are you testing on?

Comment: I am testing on 4.1.2

Comment: Is this a syntax error? Nested beneath .csstransforms.csstransitions.js #nav is a rule: ".backface-visibility(hidden);" which should read as: "backface-visibility: hidden;" ?

Comment: Not a syntax error if he's using LESS and the backface-visibility mixin he mentions, it is passing the 'hidden' argument to his mixin, which then uses it correctly, with all vendor prefixes

Comment: I'm guessing you added a `.no-js` class to your `html` element and are using javascript to replace that class for `.js`. Are you sure that code executed correctly? Also, could you add maybe add a fiddle with your scripts attached. My first instinct tells me this probably is a JS problem